# Manipulating objects in ASP.NET MVC Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I'm trying to validate phone number.  So that I declare some data annotations like this:

```
    [IsCellAcceptable(ErrorMessageResourceName = "IsCellAcceptable", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.PageResources))]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    [Display(Name = "UserCell", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.PageResources))]
    public String Cell { get; set; }
```

If  Cell is equal to 0 999 999 99 99, I want to return it as valid and I want to save it like this: 09999999999. But IsValid function only validate it, cannot manipulate it.

```
public class IsCellAcceptableAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public IsCellAcceptableAttribute()
        : base()
    {

    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return true;
        if (value == "")
            return true;

        string phoneOutput = string.Empty;
        string phoneInput = Convert.ToString(value);
        phoneInput = phoneInput.Replace(" ", "");

        foreach (char ch in phoneInput)
        {
            if (Char.IsNumber(ch))
            {
                phoneOutput += ch;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        if (phoneOutput.Length <= 14 && phoneOutput.Length >= 10)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

**So my question is how can I manipulate objects when validating it?**

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just manipulate the value afterwards?

```
if (IsValid(value)) 
{
        // Manipulate here
        phoneNumber = phoneNumber.Replace(" ", "");
}

else
{
        // Not valid
}
```

Comment: This would definitely be the best way to do it. You don't want a function such as `isValid()` to have any side effects - that would be really confusing to anyone else looking at your code. Instead, you might consider writing an extension method for `string` which cleans the input, that you can use as JuStDaN suggests.